# Rails validates uniqueness with repetitions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique

I want validate uniqueness with a given number of repetitions, for example allowed three users with the same name.

```
User id: 1, name: "user"
User id: 2, name: "user"
User id: 3, name: "user"
```

But you can not create a fourth user with the same name. What should I do:

1. Create validates_uniqueness_of with params?
2. Or create custom validation?

I would be grateful for examples.

Comment: I think you have to loop it around the `id` and check for the number of existences of that username & do validate like `existence ==3` something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom validation, such as

```
validates :validate_three_maximum

def validate_three_maximum
  if User.where(:name => "user").count >= 3 && (new_record? || name_changed?)
    errors.add(:name, "Maximum of 3 with this name")
  end
end
```

Be aware that database uniqueness checks in your application are prone to race conditions: See [Concurrency and Integrity](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html).

EDIT: added new_record? + name_changed? check as updating a record won't count towards the 3.